How can one check if a page exceeds the page margin?
I have a multipage document (a research paper) that I generated with latex. How can one check if a page exceeds the page margin? An ideal solution would minimize the amount of manual work.

Example of a page that exceeds the page margin:

(the vertical black margin was added with \usepackage{showframe})

Example of what I mean by page margin (the red rectangle shows the page margin):


Example of publication venue specifying page margins: https://acl-org.github.io/ACLPUB/formatting.html (mirror)


Left margin: 2.5 cm

Right margin: 2.5 cm

Top margin: 2.5 cm

Bottom margin: 2.5 cm




Reason why I only care about page margins rather than all overfull boxes: some overfull boxes are not important in my case. E.g., consider the following two versions of the same table:
Version 1 of the table has an overfull box (Overfull \hbox (8.53592pt too wide)), because it uses \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}:



Version 2 of the table does not have an overfull box, because it uses \begin{minipage}{1\columnwidth} (thanks Mico for the fix):

but the 2 versions of the table are both fine for me.
(The original page overflow shown in https://i.sstatic.net/BMhnpdzu.png was fixed via https://i.sstatic.net/OlncKch1.png)
Table code (but I'm looking for an answer to the question is "How can one check if a page exceeds the page margin?", and the table is within the page margin so it's not an issue. I just used the table as an example to explain why I only care about page margins rather than all overfull boxes):
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} % Adjust the width as needed
%\begin{minipage}{1\columnwidth} % Adjust the width as needed
\small
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Metric} & \textbf{Acrobat} & \textbf{Photoshop} \\ \midrule
No. of QA pairs & 131\footnote{\hsize=0.9\linewidth The count includes 22 composite questions. We focus on non-composite questions in this work (data analysis and experimentation). Composite Questions are an area for future exploration.}  & 96 \\ 
Avg. length of questions (words) & 8.80 & 12.74 \\
Avg. length of answers (words) & 118.71 & 98.71 \\
Total no. of web pages & 146  & 349 \\
Total no. of sections & 1281 & 2478 \\
Avg. no. of sections per web page & 8.78 & 7.1 \\
Avg. length of the section (words) & 135.75 & 121.09  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\captionsetup{width=0.9\linewidth}
\caption{Statistics for the Adobe Acrobat and Photoshop datasets.}
\label{tab:statistics_dataset}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}


The question is not duplicate of Do I have to care about bad boxes? since there are solutions other than looking at overfull box warnings, e.g. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/722212/11400 for two other solutions.

I have crossposted the question at:

Quora
Reddit


Read the output on the terminal when you compile? Or look in the log? 'Overfull hbox' is the usual warning. Or use draft mode for visual alerts?

Look for Overfull \hbox warnings in the log file/terminal. See What does "overfull hbox" mean? some general solutions, or Panic on overfull \hbox for a really aggressive solution.

Please mention in your question that you cross post. It is a waste of people's time not to.

@mickep 100% agreed, but some people are against it and it increases the likelihood of roomba deleting the question., so I stopped doing it.

I don't think (many) people are against cross-posting per se, but people are liable to get annoyed if you cross-post without saying so and without linking the various posts to each other.

Please clarify what you mean by page margin. In particular, are you concerned with material literally overflowing past the margin and going off the page entirely, or are you concerned with material protruding into the right-hand margin (assuming your document's text flows from left to right) without also going off the page? (The latter might better be called the "text margin" instead of "page margin".)

@Mico Thanks, example of a page that exceeds the page margin: https://i.sstatic.net/BMhnpdzu.png (the vertical black margin was added with \usepackage{showframe}).

The sample image you've added strongly suggests that something went wrong in terms of setting the width of the object (possibly a minipage?) that encloses the caption and legend. Was this width maybe set to 0.5\textwidth instead of 1\columnwidth? Aside: To improve overall readability, I would also suggest placing the table between paragraphs, rather than having the table split a given paragraph in two.

@mickep Do you have a link?

@cfr crossposted on https://qr.ae/psdcT3 and https://redd.it/1dytip5. FYI: How can one search for a word that was removed during an edit? and Quora users (bots?) are copying a significant amount of Stack Exchange questions to Quora.

@DavidCarlisle thanks, looking for a general answer,  i.e. all possible use cases that could cause a page to exceed the page margin.

I don't think there can be a general answer beyond don't force the dimensions of content unless you want the results of forcing them (as if often the case if I set a box to a width of 0pt) and, for the rest, parse the terminal or log for overfull boxes. (Or use draft or one of the packages.) There can't be a finite list of possible causes except in the most abstract terms because TeX is indefinitely extensible ....

@mickep fyi, examples of edits that removed crosslinks: https://travel.stackexchange.com/revisions/156594/2,
https://travel.stackexchange.com/revisions/156634/3,
https://travel.stackexchange.com/revisions/156491/3,
https://travel.stackexchange.com/revisions/154731/5,

@DavidCarlisle thanks, here's an example of what I mean by page margin (the red rectangle shows the page margin): https://i.sstatic.net/6H3y6z1B.png

@cfr "There can't be a finite list of possible causes except in the most abstract terms because TeX is indefinitely extensible" but there could be a way to check if a page exceeds the page margin regardless of the cause,  e.g. \usepackage{showframe} + some vision model alerting if some text or other element goes beyond the drawn margins.

@DavidCarlisle thanks, reason why I only care about page margins rather than all overfull boxes: some overfull boxes are not important in my case. E.g., consider the following two versions of the same table:  Version 1 of the table has an overfull box, because it uses \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} . vs. Version 2 of the table does not have an overfull box, because it uses \begin{minipage}{1\columnwidth} (thanks Mico),
but the 2 versions are both fine for me.

Consider setting \overfullrule to something thick (like 5pt), and then check the margins of your document. Related/possible duplicate: How can I determine if a formula is out of margin?

@Werner Thanks, this is great to know.  The example with the two versions of the same table yields Overfull \hbox (8.53592pt too wide) for the version that has the Overfull \hbox warning, but that could be still be useful to ignore minor overflow cases.

@DavidCarlisle "The wrong size minipage is forcing text into the page margin, and then you say it is OK." I say OK because I don't see any overflow on the page margin https://i.sstatic.net/FcZfiAVo.png where do you see the overflow?

@DavidCarlisle ok I'll soon provide the latex source but the changes I made are rather irrelevant, since I don't see any overflow on the page margin in https://i.sstatic.net/FcZfiAVo.png despite getting Overfull \hbox warnings, which means that in my case some Overfull \hbox are useless warnings, which means the question isn't a duplicate.

@FranckDernoncourt Each stackexchange community has its own customs and habits. Just because travelling does not like crosslinks, does not mean you shouldn't add them in questions here. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz agreed and added

@DavidCarlisle " it appears that you have fixed that in both the images now in the question" no, while I don't see any overflow on the page margin in https://i.sstatic.net/FcZfiAVo.png I am still getting Overfull \hbox warnings (see  https://i.sstatic.net/A2Qd6wR8.png), which means that in my case some Overfull \hbox are useless warnings, which means the question isn't a duplicate

@DavidCarlisle Thanks. "if you ignore it and add more content, the box will visibly fill and be visibly too wide." but I don't add more content, I'm just reviewing that latex and as long as no page exceeds the page margin, then I'm fine.

@DavidCarlisle Thanks, the PDF looks fine. My job is not fixing latex, just ensuring that no page exceeds the page margin. "you still have not shown the code you used to keep the text within the minipage, originally" the original page overflow shown in https://i.sstatic.net/BMhnpdzu.png was fixed via https://i.sstatic.net/OlncKch1.png

@DavidCarlisle I agree it's not an ideal fix but I have half of thousands latex projects in overleaf but only 24h per day, most of it being not spent in latex, so at times, I just focus on ensuring that final PDF satisfies publication requirements, which in this case is page margin. Thanks very much for your feedback, point taken, will keep in mind  for the next fix!

@DavidCarlisle Thanks, this is a good point. I wasn't aware that all the unfixed issues would make it hard for tex to check the page margin overflow. It's a good idea to instead check the PDF directly.

Please never post images of code or messages. They cannot be indexed, cannot be compiled for testing without retyping and are useless to people who depend on screen-reading software. Instead, please post code and messages as plain text and add markdown to format the text as code.

@cfr added, thanks!  Note that the table is within the page margin so it's not an issue. I just used the table as an example to explain why I only care about page margins rather than all overfull boxes.

@DavidCarlisle My only job here is checking that no pages exceeds the page margin. Other people are editing latex, and I'm just checking. If they took a hammer to ensure that no pages exceeds the page margin, that'd work for me as long as it passes my check.

as I say then you should use ghostscript and check the pdf. The tex source is basically unusable and the tex warnings are being ignored, even tex errors are being ignored so there is nothing to be said from the tex side of things.

@DavidCarlisle Thanks, your comment is a valid answer.

Somewhat related: you can't worry about the output pdf while there are compilation errors (indicated by the red "73").  You need that to be gone or at worst orange.

@Teepeemm this is incorrect: 1) the question would remain the same regardless of the number of compilation errors 2) the publication editor is only complaining about the page margins.

If there is a compilation error, the output pdf is only supposed to be a guide to help fix the error.  You can't assume that the output is what you want, and you can't assume that recompiling would give the same output.  If the pdf that you happen to get satisfies someone else because the margins are fine, that's their prerogative, but something is still broken in your document.  (And it's entirely possible that the error is causing the overfull box.)

@Teepeemm I'm 100% ok with a broken document as long as it conveys its message efficiently + passes formatting requirements. I don't want to have to fix 76 errors to find the 1 error causing the overfull box (assuming it is an error that causes it).

Even if it may give different output next time it is compiled? Or be missing bits? Or the cross-references and/or citations are wrong? Or the links don't work? Or (somewhat futuristically) it is inaccessible to the visually impaired)? If you have 76 errors, it is highly unlikely you need to fix 76 errors because a single error will generate others. You may only have 1 or you may have a few more than that, but very unlikely there are 76 things to fix. The only way to know if the errors don't impair the message is to check the output line-by-line against the inputs. I'm too lazy to do that ;).

@cfr I've typically ignored errors unless myself or other authors spot issues in the PDF and so far, no complains from readers, so I guess the output of broken docs is typically fine. Not saying that it won't blow in my face one day for one paper, but the saved time makes it worth that risk.

Solutions so far:

Add \usepackage{showframe} to show page margins. Limitation: requires visual inspection.
Look for "Overfull \hbox warnings" in the log file/terminal as suggested by Max Chernoff. Limitation: doesn't always mean a page margin overflow.
Some conferences have only checkers that include page margin checks, e.g. https://huggingface.co/spaces/teelinsan/aclpubcheck (code).


Please edit your question with further information rather than commenting on your reasons for rejecting suggestions proposed so far. Details in the form of a minimal working example and some idea of what you're looking for would be helpful.

@cfr thanks, an ideal solution would minimize the amount of manual work. Not rejecting, but just mentioning limitations.

an overfull box  always means something is overflowing and it's usually obvious from the shown box contents where that is

A third solution would be specify the document class-level option draft. That way, any instances of overflows will be prominently marked with a "slug". (Yes, that's official TeX jargon.)

A second limititation of the showframe- or frameline-based approach arises in two-column layouts: The framelines help spot overfull boxes in the right-hand columns, but not in the left-hand columns.

why do you care more about overfull page boxes than other overfull warnings? For example in a two column document (or a table) an overfull box in the first column will under-print the text in the next column rather than exceed page margins, but this is, if anything, worse.

Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - From Review

@Marijn This is an answer, not additional information.

@Franck since you mention limitations for each of the solutions I classified it as 'incomplete answer', and the "Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question" according to the automatic review comment. I would have expected that you put these approaches in the question and say "these do not answer my question because of their limitations, I'm looking for an answer without the limitatons".

@Marijn thanks, limited answer != incomplete answer. But anyway, I added solution #3 (https://huggingface.co/spaces/teelinsan/aclpubcheck), which has no limitation for me.
